# Google sheet ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to we can pass column ranges in numbers like rows

example basically if we want to count column A we write =COUNT(A:A)
I want to count column a by its column index =COUNT(1:1)

Comment: `=COUNT(1:1)` should work just fine. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Mmm, what you can do is to create some kind of OFFSET from A1. Let's say you input the column number in B1:

```
=COUNTA(OFFSET($A$1,0,B1-1):OFFSET($A$1,ROWS(A:A)-1,B1-1))
```

In this example, see as I've put input 4 and counts the 6 elements in column D:

[image]

Comment: Yes using offset is a good idea! Maybe using the height parameter e.g. =count(offset(A1,0,1,rows(A:A))) for column 2.

Answer (score 0):

If your sheet has columns A to Z, you can use

```
=count(index(A:Z,,1))
```

More generally

```
=COUNT(index(A1:indirect(address(rows(A:A),columns(1:1))),,1))
```

perhaps.

[image]

to count column 1 then column 2.

Comment: My goal is to build a function that function search in headers that is pass in it if the pass argument match in header than that whole column used as range in such function like COUNTA, COUNTIF etc